# Firebase rules -- can't access my collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire

My firestore rule for a collection in my database looks like this

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /user_data/{accountId}/nfts {
       allow read: if request.auth.token.email[0:42].lower() == acountId.lower();
       //allow read : if true;
       allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

In my request, path is defined:

`path = "/user_data/0x59f5b98d5b5fc01c8ae10238b93618053e62be20/nfts"`

This is the correct path of the collection.

The email address of the requested firebase user is

`0x59f5b98d5b5fc01c8ae10238b93618053e62be20@mysite.com`
<-- 42 chars before @ --->

when I attempt a read using:

```
  let snap = db.collection(path).valueChanges() 
  let val = await firstValueFrom(snap);
```

I keep getting permission denied.  It seems clear that is some problem with the `allow read` because if change it to `allow read : if true;` I get back the all the documents in the collection.

I can'tseem to determine what is wrong with with the `allow read` statement.

Comment: Can you add a log statement to verify that the user's email address is what you expect at the time of the query, using the client user object and not the path? You might also want to try the security rules emulator to better debug issues with rules. https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#visualize_security_rules_activity

Comment: I have been logged both the the request path as well as the user object's email address,  but was wondering how I could look at what is actually being delivered to the rules engine.  I will check out the emulator maybe it will help me track down the problem.  But I guess the syntax is directionally right?

Comment: Alas just a typo in the rule-- "acountId" should be "accountId"

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the circle

```
  allow get: if true;
  allow list: if request.auth != null;
  allow create: if true;
  allow update: if true;
  allow delete: if false
```

You can control through the existing sections you have with a request uid or email

allow get: if request.auth != null && request.auth.email == resource.data.{"Here use ur doc name example email"};

request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid  Or ;